# Managing a technocrat group

Tags: world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension, realm-management

Are there any rules in *Mage: the Ascension* regarding the management of a large technocrat organization like the crew of a large spaceship?  Rules for managing a mage group also works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### There are no such rules

The books that deal with these closest are *Guide to the Technocracy* and *Convention Book: Void Engineers*. However, neither go in any great detail about the leadership level, and certainly don't include specific rules on leadership actions.

That said, the listed books do offer guidance in that regard; they do include some discussion on the leadership structure, and the latter includes a sample ship and it's officers.

As a side note, "large spaceships" are not really that large in practice. The mainstay battleship of the Void Engineers has a crew of 35 (fully manned).